# Multiple text fields can't seem to enable them with a radio button

Tags: javascript, textbox, radio-button

Other than following somebody else example and trying to suit it to my needs I know zero javascript.  That's why this is such a hard fight for me else I'd just do it in PHP but PHP can't interact with elements in the document. =(

I recreated my problem in a jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Handler/baz19g8y/

All my select and input fields have the same class name.  And then based up on which radio button is selected the all the fields become editable.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="" method='post'>
    <table class="mgmtchg">
        <tr>
            <th>Management Role</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Update</th>
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <select name="mgmt-role-0" class="mgmt-0 form-field role-drop" disabled>
                    <option value="mgmt0" selected>Head Coach</option>
                    <option value="mgmt1">Assistance Coach</option>
                    <option value="mgmt2">Team Manager</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <input type="hidden" name="mgmt-id-0" value="25" />
                <input type="hidden" name="team-id-0" value="11" />
                <input type="text" name="mgmt-name-0" class="mgmt-0 form-field mgmt-name-field" disabled value="Ed Frederickson" />
            </td>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <input type="text" name="email-0" class="mgmt-0 form-field mgmt-email-field" disabled value="tealfred@sbcglobal.net" />
            </td>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <input type="text" name="phone-0" class="mgmt-0 form-field mgmt-phone-field" disabled value="317-987-3095" />
            </td>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <div class="chgradio">
                    <input type="radio" name="utype0" value="upd-0" id="mgmtupdate-0" class="css-radiobox">
                    <label for="mgmtupdate-0" class="css-label radGroup2"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="mgmttd">
                <div class="chgradio">
                    <input type="radio" name="utype0" value="del-0" id="mgmtdelete-0" class="css-radiobox">
                    <label for="mgmtdelete-0" class="css-label radGroup2"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And this is the javascript I'm attempting to use which of course can be found in the jsfiddle link in the beginning of this post:

```
document.getElementById('mgmtupdate-0').onchange = displayTextBox;
document.getElementById('mgmtdelete-0').onchange = displayTextBox;

var textBox = document.getElementsByClassName('mgmt-0');

function displayTextBox(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.value)
    if (evt.target.value == "upd-0") {
        textBox.disabled = false;
    } else {
        textBox.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

I'd like to learn javascript but it seems so intimidating and overly wordy!

I hope somebody can help!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns a collection. textBox.disabled is not a function of the collection. you'd rather loop through the collection:

```
textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('mgmt-0');

for(var i=0; i< textboxes.length; i++) { 
  textboxes[i].removeAttribute("disabled")
}
```

Comment: I understand what your saying but I'm not sure on how to implement this.  Main reason I need to learn javascript =(

Comment: well, practice makes perfect! I've updated the fiddle. First "onchange" is not an event fired by buttons. Second, you wish to remove the disabled attribute on click: http://jsfiddle.net/baz19g8y/16/